# Is "I wonder whom you make cry" a correct sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, objects, indirect-objects, direct-objects

I would like to say *"You made someone cry. I wonder whom."* in only one sentence. And now this is what I've got:

> I wonder whom you made cry.

To me, though, it sounds pretty odd that there isn't an object right after *"made"*, as opposed to *"made someone"*.

Is this a correct sentence? Or is there another possibility of saying it?

Comment: I will add that your sentence sounds fine to me, if a bit old-fashion and formal.  Another way (also old fashion / poetic) "I wonder who was made to cry."

Comment: *I broke the thing I made.* There is nothing after *made* at all. What makes you think there has to be? Or *I gave it to the person for whom it was made.*

Comment: @Jasson Bassford I really haven't thought of this earlier. Thanks for the remark. Although I just felt that sentence felt very odd and not idiomatic, as opposed to *"I broke the thing I made"*

Answer (score -2):

According to Webster's Dictionary, traditional grammar rules deem the word "who" is correct for the subject of a sentence or a clause, and the word "whom" is used for the object of a verb or preposition.  The word "whom" is becoming less frequent, and it is more often seen in formal writing or when someone wants to affect a formal demeanor.

A typical example is when someone knocks on the door, the reply is "Who is it?" **not** "Whom is there?"

When you are dealing with "whom" and confusion about objects, it can often clarify things by changing statements into questions.  After all "whom" is a question word even though it often isn't listed as such because it is going out of fashion.

Change your sentence to a question.

> "Who did you make cry?"

or if you want to sound more formal:

> "Whom did you make cry, I wonder?"

You are correct that the verb "to make" takes an object complement like "someone".  Here, the answer to the question *is* the object complement. The answer could be a person's name or "Someone." In the query's example,the construction is correct, but  the object complement is whom.

Change the structure of the question and you would need to change the object complement.

For example:

> Did you make someone cry, I wonder?

Comment: "I wonder who you made cry." is the closest idiomatic statement to the example in the question. I wonder why you felt it should be changed into a question.

Comment: "It is whom" is incorrect all the way around. The verb "be" is an intransitive verb and does not take an object according to traditional principles of grammar. I shall reverse my downvote if you edit your answer to make it sensible.